# How to assgin multiple different images to UIProgressbar in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

[image]in my application want to assign 6 different type of images on progressbar. All image shapes are different. some images are circle ,some images  are square and some are oval etc. So i want to create custom progressbar .
Please resolved my problem

Comment: This is a  broad question, please read FAQ. Anyway check [cocoa controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress+view)

Comment: i checked all controls in  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress+view .But not found any control which i want ...

Comment: Do you have mockup  of progress bar?

Comment: please check  my uploaded image ..

Comment: I didn't grasp exactly your requirements but something similar i found here https://github.com/YannickL/YLProgressBar